# What does Arg {Inf I(d)} means?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I am currently studying the phase-field method for fracture modeling. In an article by Miehe -"Thermodynamically consistent phase-field models of fracture: Variational principles and multi-field FE implementation", I came across on an identity that I don't understand basically it says:
$$
d = \mbox{Arg}\left\{\inf_{d \in W} I(d)\right\}.
$$
This expression came from the Euler type differential equation
$$
d(x) - l^2d''(x) = 0, 
$$
which has the solution as an exponential function
$$
d(x)\ = \ \exp(-|x|/l)
$$
Variational principle of this differential equation is ,
$$
d = \mbox{Arg}\left\{\inf_{d \in W} I(d)\right\}.
$$
with $$ W = \{d\ |\ d(0)=1,\ d(\pm \infty)=0\}$$
where I(d) is a functional defined as an integral
$$
I(d) = \frac{1}{2}\int [d^2 + l^2d'^2] dV,
$$
and $l$ is a parameter.

Can anyone tell me what does that mean?

Comment: Can you provide more context please? What is $I$? Maybe a function?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: A pdf of the mentioned article is available [here](http://www.crm.sns.it/media/course/3060/miehe+welschinger+hofacker10a.pdf).

Comment: It appears to simply be saying: find the infimum of the set $I(d)$ and return the argument, $d$, for the $I(d)$ that is the infimum.

Answer (score -1):

It returns the argument that makes the functional $I\equiv I(d)$ infimum such that the function $d$ belongs to the space of kinematically acceptable functions $W$, i.e., it satisfies the prescribed boundary conditions. It just explicitly emphasises that we are after the function (or argument) that makes the functional infimum and not the infimum value itself.